# How can I give update authority of an NFT to a program

Tags: nfts, metaplex

I want my program or the owner of the program to be the update authority of Metaplex NFT.

Is there a way to set update authority without user sending keypair and signing?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to set the authority to a PDA of your program.  Your program would then need to provide otherwise authenticated wrapper instructions that CPI into the metaplex program(s) to perform whatever actions you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will always need the current update authority to sign the transaction if you want to change the update authority.You do not need the current owner to sign.

Easiest off chain method would be to use [metaboss set](https://metaboss.rs/set.html#set-update-authority) to change the update authority